# Print Y-m-d list of business days based on two dates from form data compared to MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date, between

I have these two `MySQL` tables:

```
desc students;
+---------------------------+---------------+
| Field                     | Type          |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| student_id                | INT(11)       |
| student_firstname         | VARCHAR(255)  |
| student_lastname          | VARCHAR(255)  |
+---------------------------+---------------+

desc studentabsence;
+---------------------------+---------------+
| Field                     | Type          |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| student_id                | INT(11)       |
| student_absence_startdate | date          |
| student_absence_enddate   | date          |
+---------------------------+---------------+
```

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    students s 
        INNER JOIN studentabsence sa 
            ON s.student_id = sa.student_id
WHERE s.student_id = '1'
```

I get the following output:

```
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+
| student_id | student_firstname | student_lastname| student_id | student_absence_startdate | student_absence_enddate |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+
|       1    | John              | Doe             | 1          | 2012-08-01                | 2012-08-08              |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Now, I have a `<form>` where a user can select a student, and a date range. I wonder if there is possible to compare the two dates of the user choice to the database values and, if there is a match echo all the business days between that range where the student has data.

So, using the above example if a user posts the following form:

```
student_id = '1'
student_absence_startdate = '2012-08-02'
student_absence_enddate = '2012-08-06'
```

I would like to `echo`:

```
2012-08-02
2012-08-03
2012-08-06
```

Any pointers in the right direction is higly appreciated.

Comment: Change the field type from `varchar` to `date`. Then you can perform date operations on it

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this response only on the basis of query. Also if you keep your data type as date would help you alot.

```
SELECT * FROM students s
INNER JOIN studentabsence sa ON s.student_id = sa.student_id
AND s.student_id = '1'
AND student_absence_startdate >= 2012-08-02
AND student_absence_enddate < 2012-08-06
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. The datatype was date but I forgot to edit this while posting my question. I am just curious on how your reply would be an answer to my question?

Comment: David  What i infered from your question is you wanted to write some query using dates. I don't know how this query can help you in doing echo, due to I have no PHP experience.